# Collatz Conjecture: Why does my program go crazy after a certain number?

Tags: c++, math

So I am playing around a bit with programming in my spare time and I decided to try writing a program that would use the collatz conjecture to decompose numbers according to certain rules.

Long story short:
if the number is even, divide it by two.
if the number is odd, multiply it by 3 and add 1.

So it works for all smaller numbers but if I hit a certain number (5 000 000 000 triggers it, but 1 000 000 000 doesn't, I am not sure what is the minimum number to trigger the bug).

So when you enter a number too big the program goes crazy and spits out lots of numbers (some of them even go negative?) and it doesn't terminate. It just gets into an infinite loop.

I am really curious why does it do that and what is the source of this behaviour.

Keep in mind this is just me being curious and I don't actually have to do this to save my job or anything, I am doing it purely for fun so if you're a busy person don't waste time :).

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void collatz(long unsigned int value);

int main() {

    long unsigned int input;

    while (true) {
        cout << "Please enter a starting number(0 to terminate): ";
        cin >> input;

        if (input <= 0) {
            break;
        }

        collatz(input);
        cout << endl;
    }

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}

void collatz(long unsigned int value) {

    int steps = 0;

    long unsigned int l1 = 0, l2 = 0, l3 = 0;

    while (true) {
        steps++;

        if (l1 == 4 && l2 == 2 && l3 == 1)
        {
            cout << "Steps: " << steps << endl;
            break;
        }

        if (value % 2 == 0)
        {
            l1 = l2;
            l2 = l3;
            l3 = value;

            value = value / 2;
            cout << value << " - ";
        }
        else
        {
            l1 = l2;
            l2 = l3;
            l3 = value;
            value = value * 3;
            value = value + 1;
            cout << value << " - ";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Look up "integer overflow".

Comment: Looks like a 32 bit unsigned int overflow. A long might be the same size as an int. You could try "long long" to get bigger int.

Comment: Oh I understand it now. So basically there aren't enough bits assigned to the variable, and the value can't be stored properly? That makes a lot of sense. Thanks guys!

Comment: More precisely, the type `long unsigned int` only has enough bits to represent values on the range `0 to 4,294,967,295`, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx) for other ranges (you will probably want an `unsigned long long`)

Comment: You can also the uint64_t type if you (and all the size variants) if you want to explicitly specify your needs